# Using methods on every item in an Array

Tags: java

I have a string array that is being filled dynamically.... I would like to run this function:

```
String[] name = request.getParameterValues("name");
myString = name.substring(0, name.length() - 2);
```

Now, I know that this wont run, because substring and length methods aren't used for the whole array.  Since i dont know how many items will be in this array at any given run time, is there anyway to run the substring/length function for every item in this array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use you can use `length` field of the `name` array.
Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; ++i)
{
    String s = name[i];
    String sbtr = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
}
```

Or a better approach would be this:

```
for (String s: name)
{
    String sbtr = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I dont run java 5, so I have to use the bottom example. thank you

Comment: Any particular reason you're using such an old version of Java? The current release is Java 6, and Java 7 Milestone 13 was released in February.

Comment: no reason....just haven't done it, I honestly didn't realize they were on Java 7.

Comment: Don't worry about Java 7 yet, it's not actually released yet. IMO, by not using at least Java 5, you're really missing out on [a ton of stuff](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/jett/sstamm/).

Answer (score 4):

Modern versions of Java (i.e Java 5 and later) have a special `for` syntax for arrays (and iterables):

```
String[] name = request.getParameterValues("name");
for (String s: name) {
    String myString = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a [`for` loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). There are a couple different ways to do this. The most basic way:

```
String[] names = request.getParameterValues("name");

for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
{
    String name = names[i];
    String myString = name.substring(0, name.length() - 2);
}
```

Or you can use the ["enhanced for"](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/the-enhanced-for-loop.html) (also called a "for-each" — it's just syntactic sugar):

```
String[] names = request.getParameterValues("name");

for (String name : names)
{
    String myString = name.substring(0, name.length() - 2);
}
```